# Issues with a simple SQL Regex

Tags: java, sql, regex

I have a Task to split the columns out of a SQL Statement. This worked well for me with a simple Java split on ",". But now i have an issue with additional commas inside the column.
I guess the answer to this problem is pretty simple, but it will not get into my mind.

Example:

Source:

```
"Col_A BIGINT , COL_B TIMESTAMP , COL_C DECIMAL(10,30) , COL_D VARCHAR(20)"
```

My wanted Output:

```
Array[0] = Col_A BIGINT
Array[1] = COL_B TIMESTAMP
Array[2] = COL_C DECIMAL(10,30)
Array[3] = COL_D VARCHAR(20)
```

The real (and abvious) output:

```
Array[0] = Col_A BIGINT
Array[1] = COL_B TIMESTAMP
Array[2] = COL_C DECIMAL(10
Array[3] = 30)
Array[4] = COL_D VARCHAR(20)
```

The Obvious Problem is the comma between the two decimals (COL_C).

Now i am asking you if there is a nice solution on this Problem. I really want to use a single split to receive the different columns. But how can i avoid the wrong split at the decimal description.

I hope you guys can understand my problem. English is not my native language.

Comment: You have spaces around `,`, `split(" , ")`. Else, use `split("\\s*,\\s*(?![^)]*\\))")` (it is more a work around that will fail with some input later, best is to use *matching* approach).

Comment: Could you give the code you are using for this output ?

Comment: Well the spaces were too obvious for me. My original statement is created by a DB2-Look. The spaces should be there every single time. I will give it a try, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just split the given string with regex : `,(?!\d)`

Find the  `,` which is not followed by digit.

Code sample:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Col_A BIGINT , COL_B TIMESTAMP , COL_C DECIMAL(10,30) , COL_D VARCHAR(20)".split(",(?!\\d)")));
```

[Demo and Explaination of regex](https://regex101.com/r/aE2aR7/1)

Comment: However, this still matches commas inside parentheses.

Comment: Yes. But according to OP parantheses always having number that is size of column.